# How to Group the XML Tags

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to modify xml format by grouping the Elements. In below format, Article's first three elements (ID, NAME and CITY) will be used 
to group MEDIA elements, Meaning if  (ID, NAME and CITY) elements are having the same information holding by other three elements in another article then MEDIA elements will be grouped under (ID, NAME and CITY) elements.

For Example:

Input

```
<Article>
    <ID>100</ID>
    <NAME>A</NAME>
    <CITY>XX</CITY>
    <MEDIA>
        <MEDIANAME>PPP</MEDIANAME>
        <MEDIACOLOR>RED></MEDIACOLOR>
    </MEDIA>
</Article>
<Article>
    <ID>100</ID>
    <NAME>A</NAME>
    <CITY>XX</CITY>
    <MEDIA>
        <MEDIANAME>PPC</MEDIANAME>
        <MEDIACOLOR>YELLOW></MEDIACOLOR>
    </MEDIA>
</Article>
<Article>
    <ID>101</ID>
    <NAME>B</NAME>
    <CITY>YY</CITY>
    <MEDIA>
        <MEDIANAME>PPX</MEDIANAME>
        <MEDIACOLOR>BLACK></MEDIACOLOR>
    </MEDIA>
</Article>
<Article>
    <ID>101</ID>
    <NAME>B</NAME>
    <CITY>YY</CITY>
    <MEDIA>
        <MEDIANAME>PPZ</MEDIANAME>
        <MEDIACOLOR>PURPLE></MEDIACOLOR>
    </MEDIA>
</Article>
```

Output

```
<Article>
    <ID>100</ID>
    <NAME>A</NAME>
    <CITY>XX</CITY>
    <MEDIA>
        <MEDIANAME>PPP</MEDIANAME>
        <MEDIACOLOR>RED></MEDIACOLOR>
    </MEDIA>
    <MEDIA>
        <MEDIANAME>PPC</MEDIANAME>
        <MEDIACOLOR>YELLOW></MEDIACOLOR>
    </MEDIA>
</Article>
<Article>
    <ID>101</ID>
    <NAME>B</NAME>
    <CITY>YY</CITY>
    <MEDIA>
        <MEDIANAME>PPX</MEDIANAME>
        <MEDIACOLOR>BLACK></MEDIACOLOR>
    </MEDIA>
    <MEDIA>
        <MEDIANAME>PPZ</MEDIANAME>
        <MEDIACOLOR>PURPLE></MEDIACOLOR>
    </MEDIA>
</Article>
```

May I know how can I achieve this using java ? I'll be receiving xml in this format only so I have only option left is to just modify file to group the elements. Its just a sample, actual file is much bigger than this and more number of elements.

Note: I can write code but not able to find any approach to achieve this. Any point of views or Ideas are Welcome :)

Comment: Which part of the task presents the problem for you? Do you know how to read XML files? Do you know how to group data in memory? Do you know how to write data to an XML file?

Comment: @yole, How can I take the reference of first three elements of Article to check in others for same info and come to add thier MEDIA elements if find any match ? Yes I know how to read XML, Group of data in this case is am not able to find any way, Yes I know how to write data to xml. :)   Writing to data to xml is not case here (already have a xml), secondly can you tell if you read xml how can we make these groups ? :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you need to do.

1. You need to read your XML into Java. There is a library called JAXB that does just that. JAXB will help you marshal and unmarshall Java to / from XML.
2. You need to define your information model. By the looks of it you have a class called Article with 3 (string) fields called id, name, and city which together form the unique identifier of an instance of that class. You then have a list of Media objects each of which is made up of a name and color.
3. In your information model you need to overwrite your equals() and hashcode() functions so that equality is found when 2 instances of the Article class have the same 3 id, name, and city.

Now, use JAXB to read the XML file into a `List<Article>` that will contain all the articles in your source XML.

Then, create a Map. Then iterate over the List and add each item to the Map (`map.put(article,article)`). If the map already contains that Article, you grab it and update its media section. For instance: `map.get(currentArticle).getMedia.addAll(currentArticle.getMedia())`

When you are done, you can marshall your Java back into XML.

NB: the reason for using a Map rather than a Set is that you need to be able to retrieve the object and modify it which in a Set you cannot.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but never used JAXB library. Okay I will try using that. Is that possible you could share any sample code for this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on David's answer, you don't necessarily need jaxb (although it may make your life easier). Your xml file is missing a root node, which will result in an exception being thrown due to invalid format. It should be like

```
<Articles>
    <Article>...</Article>
    ...
</Articles>
```

Using just standard java7, you can declare an `XPath` object

```
private final XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
```

And use that in the method that reads your xml document into Java objects like so:

```
String file = "/path/to/your/xml/file.xml";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(fis);
NodeList nl = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/Articles/Article", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    articles.add(new Article(nl.item(i)));
}
List<Article> merged = mergeMedia(articles);
```

with an `Article` class like

```
private class Article {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private List<Media> media;
    // getters, setters
    public Article(Node node) throws Exception {
        this.id = (String) xpath.evaluate("ID", node, XPathConstants.STRING);
        this.name = (String) xpath.evaluate("NAME", node, XPathConstants.STRING);
        this.city = (String) xpath.evaluate("CITY", node, XPathConstants.STRING);
        this.media = new ArrayList<Media>();
        media.add(new Media((Node) xpath.evaluate("MEDIA", node, XPathConstants.NODE)));
    }
}
```

and a similar media class.

Implement a method to merge the objects as you described (`mergeMedia(articles)` in my example), returning a `List` or some other `Collection`, then convert that back into xml as needed.